# CSS custom font works in landscape mode but not in portrait mode of iPad

Tags: css, ipad

I am trying to use an custom font for my iPad site, and it works great for landscape but not for portrait mode.

my HTML structure

```
body
  #wrapper
    blahblah
```

**Landscape style** - works

```
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape){
    @font-face {
        font-family: custom_helvetica;
        src: url('../includes/helvetican.ttf');
    }

    #wrapper {
       width:/*768px;*/1024px;
       font-family: custom_helvetica;
       margin:auto;
    }
```

**Portrait CSS** - doesn't show the form

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
    @font-face {
        font-family: custom_helvetica;
        src: url('../includes/helvetican.ttf');
    }

    #wrappper {
        width:768px;
        font-family: helvetica;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the selector correct?

## wrap**p**per maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Your font-family is still `custom_helvetica` but in your `#wrapper` you use `helvetica`. ***edit:*** And of course take a look at Jeepstone's answer!